# Poisson distribution- mosquitos question

Tags: probability

Can anyone help me in these questions?

I am not sure if I am thinking in the right way

When one is camping, mosquitoes are observed to land on one’s body at
an average rate of 3 per minute. Using the Poisson distribution:

a) What is the probability that 6 or more mosquitoes land in a
single minute?

I did:

$\lambda=3$

$P(X>6)=1-P(X=5)$

which is :

$1- \frac{(e^-3).3^5}{5!}= 0.899$

b) What is the probability that no mosquito lands for five
consecutive minutes?

I did:

I changed the $\lambda, for \lambda = \frac{5}{3}=1.6 $, since if 1 mosquito in 3 minutes then in 5 minutes will land 1.6 mosquitos in average.

Then my answer is:

$\lambda = \frac{5}{3}=1.6 $

$ P(X=0)=  \frac{(e^-1.6).1.6^0}{0!}=0.202 $

c) Find the probability that the time between two consecutive
mosquito landings is less than 10 seconds.

I did:

$1 minute->60 seconds $ , then 3 minutes 180 seconds,then 10 seconds is 0.16 minutes

Because of that now $\lambda =0.16$

$ P(X=1)=  \frac{(e^-0.16).0.16^1}{1!}= $ for 1 mosquito in $\lambda=1$

I did:

then for two consecutive mosquitos will be:

$( \frac{(e^-0.16).0.16^1}{1!})^2= 0.0186$

d) If a person applies a mosquito repellant, the average rate
drops to 1 per minute. How do answers for the questions in parts
a, b and c change?

I did:

$\lambda=1$ since now it is 1 mosquito per minute

Then:

for a) it will be :

$P(X>6)=1-P(X=5)$

which is :

$1- \frac{(e^-1).1^5}{5!}$

For b) $\lambda = 5 $  because 1 mosquito in 1 minute, then in 5 minutes will be 5 mosquitos

$ P(X=0)=  \frac{(e^-5).5^0}{0!} $

And for c)

$\lambda =60 seconds$ since now the average is 1 mosquito per minute and 1 minute has 60 seconds.

Then:

$( \frac{(e^-0.16).0.16^1}{1!})^2 $ for two consecutive mosquitos.

I think I am doing it wrong.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

a)
$$
\begin{align}
P(X\ge6)
&=1-P(X\le5)\\
&=1-\left(\frac{3^0}{0!}+\frac{3^1}{1!}+\frac{3^2}{2!}+\frac{3^3}{3!}+\frac{3^4}{4!}+\frac{3^5}{5!}\right)e^{-3}\\
&=1-\frac{92}5e^{-3}\\[6pt]
&=0.083917942
\end{align}
$$
b) $\lambda=15$ ($3$ land in one minute). The probability is
$$
\begin{align}
P(X=0)
&=\frac{15^0}{0!}e^{-15}\\[6pt]
&=0.00000030590232
\end{align}
$$
c) $\lambda=\frac12$ (half a landing in $10$ seconds).
$$
\begin{align}
1-P(X=0)
&=1-\frac{\left(\frac12\right)^0}{0!}e^{-1/2}\\[6pt]
&=0.39346934
\end{align}
$$